# How can I show 4 latest articles in ascending order?

Tags: views

Lets say I have 10 articles, tenth being the last one created.
I want my view block to show 4 latest articles, but in ASCENDING order.

7,8,9,10 - something like this.

Can I somehow filter out the exact number of latest articles?
[image: View options]

Comment: Combination of view filters, view  sorting and displaying a specified number of items (5 in my example).

Comment: Can you add a screesnhot of your current view's configuration to your question?

Comment: Can't you simply change the order from the dialogue that appears when you click on "Content: Authored on (desc)"?

Comment: Oldest 4 articles would be shown then.

Comment: Ah now I understand! Unfortunately I'm mobile right now and can't test it properly. Will return later. Thinking of some preprocess function and/or a quick custom views template.

Comment: Not to worry, I found out that I don't need articles to be shown in Ascending order, so everything is alright. But still, i find this issue quite interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just output the rows you need and reverse them with CSS.

```
.view-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

Comment: +1 Absolutely agreed! Solve a simple problem with a simple solution. No extra processing or database queries needed. :)

Comment: This definitely seems like the best solution. Though I was hoping for more site building solution.